# Comparison operator and function references

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1

Referencing a function as the left-hand side of the `-eq` operator produces
results that I can't explain:

```
PS C:\> function mj { 23 }
PS C:\> mj -eq 23
23
PS C:\> mj -eq 45
23
```

The first case almost makes it seem as though the function's return value is
[being interpreted as a
collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators)
of size one (maybe to accommodate functions with multiple statements), but that
theory doesn't hold for the second case.

Referencing the function from within a grouping operator or as a sub-expression
yields more intuitive results:

```
PS C:\> (mj) -eq 23
True
PS C:\> (mj) -eq 45
False
PS C:\> $(mj) -eq 23
True
PS C:\> $(mj) -eq 45
False
```

Given these more predictable forms, the practical response to the first
examples may be ["don't do
that."](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/7570350-the-patient-says-doctor-it-hurts-when-i-do-this)
Still, I'd like to understand what's going on since I'm concerned about
where/how the underlying behavior could impact other code.

```
PS C:\> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      19041  1320
```

Comment: when you do `mj -eq 23` without the grouping operator `(...)` powershell thinks you're trying to pass the argument `23` to the parameter `-eq` of the function `mj`

Comment: To see this in action, try `function mj($eq) { $eq + 1 }` instead. Fun! If you *really* want to mess with people's minds, make the function return a boolean instead.

Comment: The `-eq` tokens in your first examples is _not_ the operator - PowerShell interprets `eq` as a parameter name. `Get-Help about_Parsing`

Comment: Good question; the linked duplicate has some additional info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the comments have been explanatory, the [grouping operator `(..)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#grouping-operator--) is necessary not only for precedence but also, as demonstrated in the example from the Doc, it ***allows you to let output from a command participate in an expression***.

Without it, PowerShell interprets `-eq` as a parameter of the function `mj` and `23` as an argument for said parameter.

You can test this by adding [`$args`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#args) or a parameter that takes [`ValueFromRemainingArguments`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-7.2#valuefromremainingarguments-argument) to your function:

```
function mj { 23; $args }

function mjWithRemainingArgs {
    param(
        [parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments)]
        $remargs
    )

    23; $remargs
}

PS /> mj -eq 23
23
-eq
23

PS /> mjWithRemainingArgs -eq 45
23
-eq
45
```